# No apks will install

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, custom-roms, installation, apk

I have been repeatedly trying to install an apk on my moto g lte (1st gen). Nothing will install. Apks worked initially, but it stopped working at one point

su
pm install [apk]
Returns invalid URI.
The name is all standard chars.

su
pm install -r [apk]
Returns container error.

SOLVED
I had managed to corrupt my SD card which meant the apk files could not be installed upon my phone. Taking out the SD fixed it.

Comment: 1. Is this a problem with an specific apk, or are you having trouble with installing any apk? 2) What error do you see on screen when you try to install the apk using standard procedure (tap and install)? 3) Did you consider `logcat` to capture the logs during the occurrence of the error? 4) Could you detail more about: *Apks worked initially, but it stopped working at one point*?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting logcat. I am an idiot sometimes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Corrupted SD card meant I could not install anything.